# Leveling second story bedroom floor

Tags: floor, leveling

I've owned this house for 12 years and it's had this problem since we bought it.  There had been some foundation settling in one corner, that has since been stabilized with poly foam injection, but has caused on out-of-level floor issue in the corner second-floor bedroom by about an 1" to 1.25". (The garage below has a similar issue, but it's not a big deal as far as I'm concerned.) The room has been in use all this time, but our daughter has since moved out and we'd like to correct it.

I've pulled the carpet up and the baseboards out and it appears the subfloor is glued/screwed down to the decking beneath it.  I had initially thought about pulling up the subfloor, sistering on some new joists, level, and reinstalling it, but the glued/screwed has stymied me.

I've also considered using some of that 'self leveler' but that doesn't seem like the right way to handle this.

Can anyone offer some suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Odd sub floor to be glued to joists.  Are you sure it is not a second layer of sub floor glued to the bottom sub floor?  Does the floor need to be level?  Does it feel odd to people?

Comment: There's not another floor below with the same issue? Have you considered shimming between the foundation and its sill plate? For a typical stem wall detail, there could be some roto-hammering for longer anchors into the foundation. And the proposition probably doesn't sound good if it obsoletes the work you've already done.

Comment: @crip659 yes, the room is small so it is definitely noticeable, especially as we want to put LVP in there.  And sorry, yes, I think it's two layers, top-most is glued/screwed to the layer below it.

Comment: LVP does not care if there is a slope, only if the floor if flat, a long straight edge that does not show differences.  If the floor feels odd, then either remove the sub floor/s to fix, or work from the top.  As long as the floor is solid, then it becomes if you feel odd walking or not on it.  Perfect level is usually only required for pool tables, anything else is if it feels odd.

Comment: @crip659 Yea, it doesn't need to be perfect, but it's definitely noticeable.  Sounds like getting the subfloor out is the way to go.

Comment: Or just put level platforms under furniture, and odds are nobody but you and the cats will notice the remaining tilt... which has been my solution.)